# Drawing circle at centre of JFrame doesn't update after `repaint()`

Tags: java, swing, jframe, point

I am writing a program which involves creating a JFrame and drawing a circle inside it using `drawOval()` from the Graphics class. I have reached a problem where I am trying to create a point at the centre of the JFrame, and then draw my circle with this pont being the x and y coordinates of the circle. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.Point;

class MouseJFrameMotion  extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener{

    int circleXcenter;
    int circleYcenter;  
    int circleRadius = 50;
    boolean show = false;

    public MouseJFrameMotion(){       
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){     

        super.paint(g);

        if(show){
            g.drawOval(circleXcenter,circleYcenter, circleRadius*2,circleRadius*2);
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

    }

    Point frameCenter = new Point((this.getWidth()/2), (this.getHeight()/2));

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        int xLocation = e.getX();
        int yLocation = e.getY();   
        show = true;
        circleXcenter = (int) frameCenter.getX();
        circleYcenter = (int) frameCenter.getY();
        repaint();
    }
}

public class GrowingCircle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MouseJFrameMotion  myMouseJFrame = new MouseJFrameMotion();
        myMouseJFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        myMouseJFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `main()` function, I set the size of the JFrame to 500x500. However, when the circle is drawn, it's x and y coordinates are (0,0) when I expect them to be (250, 250) based on `Point frameCenter` after `repaint()` is called. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't override paint of JFrame, there a JRootPane, contentPane and other components between the user and the frames surface which can interfere with the painting. Instead, use a JPanel and override its paintComponent method

Comment: It looks like your `frameCenter` should initialize to (0,0), since the size of the JFrame is not set when it's being called.  Try changing it to be initialized with the correct value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two things...

1. Don't override `paint` of `JFrame`, there a `JRootPane`, `contentPane` and other components between the user and the frames surface which can interfere with the painting. Instead, use a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method
2. At the time `Point frameCenter = new Point((this.getWidth()/2), (this.getHeight()/2));` is evaluated, the frame's size is `0x0`, you need to reevaluate the `frameCenter` before you paint the circle. When you do this will depend on how dynamic you want the change to be

Comment: I didn't realise that about the problems with overriding `paint`. We have just begun studying class implementations and this was the assignment we were given. It had the majority of the code already written, and we just have to edit it to do various things. I'll ask my professor why she overrode the `paint` method, but I'm sure it was just to simplify things and have us focussing on implementations rather than the problems you explained. Thank you for the help nonetheless, I have it working as I should and I''l attempt to use a JPanel instead now.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I think you need both repaint() and revalidate() method

Comment: revalidate relates to the layout management API, which, if they had any other components would need to be repainted, but since they don't, it'll have no effect

Answer (score 0):

When you are constructing the class MouseJFrameMotion, the variable frameCenter is defined and set width and height 0 and it will never change. So what you can do is to calculate the frame center when you are drawing.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    int xLocation = e.getX();
    int yLocation = e.getY();
    show = true;
    Point frameCenter = new Point((this.getWidth() / 2), (this.getHeight() / 2));
    circleXcenter = (int) frameCenter.getX();
    circleYcenter = (int) frameCenter.getY();
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, all works well now, although as @MadProgrammer pointed out - I shouldn't be overwriting `paint` in `JFrame`, so I'll have to look into this now.